# How to make paging with using REST API in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, rest

I have simple task. I must get siteowners information with restapi. I have to use paging.
How to make paging with using rest api?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following URL to get users from a site group

```
http://sitename/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Owners')/users
```

REST using OData protocol. So for pagination you can use `$top` and `$skip`